# Cell value with link to another workbook not updating

Tags: excel

I noticed sometimes when I have a cell containing a link to another workbook, even if I enable Data Connection and Links, the value is just wrong until I actually open the source workbook!

I'm unsure under what circumstance this happens neither, just aware that this occasionally happens, and so makes me feel very unsecured.

Is anyone having the same trouble? And any idea how to fix/avoid this problem?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try being more specific:

```
Thisworkbook.Sheet1.Range("A1") = c.Range("C21")
```

Eventually you could also try this solution: http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/a_vba_function_to_get_a_value_from_a_closed_file/

Comment: Thanks, usually when I work with current worksheet and workbook, I only write Range("A1"), but thank you for point out, probably mine is not a good habit... I will read your link, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just referencing a cell from a closed workbook, there would be no need to open the workbook. Formulas can get a cell's value from a closed workbook.

```
 Sub GetIt()
    Range("A1") = "='C:\Users\dmorrison\Downloads\[A.xlsx]Sheet1'!$C$21"
    Range("A1").Value = Range("A1").Value
End Sub
```